# reponsive menu css3 width display: flex

Tags: css, menu, flexbox

i'm creating a reponsive menu with :
    display:flex
and i have somes issues with IE10 and Opera in the drop down menu, all others browers are ok, IE10 should accept

```
display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
```

for a vertical display, but it doesn't.
With opera, there is a fadding effect in the anchors.

there is my codepen:

http://codepen.io/dqni/pen/podvE

Comment: Your pen doesn't *have* a `-ms-flex-direction` in it anywhere (but adding it causes a different problem I'm not able to debug right now).  Opera never had prefixes for Flexbox.  Firefox does not have prefixes for the standard Flexbox properties, only the 2009 properties *and* you can't use them on absolutely positioned elements (`position: absolute` causes FF to drop the `display: flex` property).

Comment: The <preferred-size> component sets the preferred size [...] If omitted, the preferred size defaults to ‘0px’. If set to ‘auto’, the value of ‘width’ or ‘height’ (whichever is in parallel to main axis) is used as preferred size. 

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/

IE10 need to set -ms-flex-preferred-size:auto;
and then, the vertical display will be done;